# Adding BaseGamesUtils causes gradle to not sync

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-games

I am using android studio and I am attempting to add baseGamesUtils from github to a game I have made to add leaderboards.

Following the tutorial at googles developer site, I downloaded and added the baseGameUtils Module to the project and added the dependency in the module gradle file.

But when I attempt to sync this happens:

> Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'android_appcompat_library' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1b4bd95.

All SDKS are up to date, gradle is set to compileSdkVersion 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to the last upgrade (4 days ago) of the build.gradle for the library. Try to go back to the previous build.gradle from the GitHub. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. It looks to have been solved for me now as well. It only took 16hour this time around. If not for you who knows how long.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be add

```
ext {
    android_compile_version = 20
    android_version = '20'
    android_min_sdk_version = 9

    android_appcompat_library =  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    android_support_library =  'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    android_gms_library =  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5+'
}
```

to the build.gradle file for you project under allprojects{ ... }